# SimpleMembership with WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, simplemembership

Is it possible to use SimpleMembership with ASP.NET WebForms?

John Galloway's article seems to indicate that WebForms "implements OAuth on top of ASP.NET Membership".

All the other articles I've found (on StackOverflow & elsewhere) discuss SimpleMembership in the context of MVC or WebMatrix.

Anything on NuGet related to SimpleMembership is for MVC.

Is it possible, and are there any resources on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use it with WebForms.
Refer to the following 2 articles:
http://blog.osbornm.com/2010/07/21/using-simplemembership-with-asp.net-webpages
http://blogs.msmvps.com/luisabreu/blog/2012/09/24/adding-the-simplemembership-provider-to-an-asp-net-web-forms-app/