# SimpleMembershipProvider in WebSite with Profile

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, simplemembership, sqlprofileprovider

I created a new WebSite in VS2012 - NOT a project - added the connection string, created tables, and then using ASPNET CONFIGURATION created a couple of roles and an user, which in turn automatically created the appropriated tables in my database: Users, UsersInRoles, Roles, Memberships and ROLES. Pretty much working as expected. With 4.5 (SimpleMembershipProvider) it doesn't create all the stored procedures and extra code is used to with the old MemberShipProvider.

I wanted to add some fields in the Profile provider, like I use to MembershipProvider:

> ```
>  <properties>
>     <add name="myWhatEver" type="System.Int32" allowAnonymous="false"/>
>   </properties>
> ```

But when I try to call in code behind, it said "Profile" doesn't exists. So I search on the web and read that with VS2012, if you create a website, instead of a project, it doesn't come with profile by default so you have to create a custom one.

Following that I added the following code in AppCode cs:

> namespace myNameSpace
>   {
>
> ```
> public class UserProfile : ProfileBase
> {
>     public static UserProfile GetUserProfile(string username)
>     {
>         return Create(username) as UserProfile;
>     }
>     public static UserProfile GetUserProfile()
>     {
>         return Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName) as UserProfile;
>     }
>
>     [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false)]
>     public string myWhatEver1
>     {
>         get { return base["myWhatEver1"] as string; }
>         set { base["myWhatEver1"] = value; }
>     }
> }
> ```

In WebConfig:

```
<profile defaultProvider="MYProfileProvider" inherits="myNameSpace.UserProfile">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MYProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="MYDBConn"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="MYMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MYMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MYDBConn"  applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="MYRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MYRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="MYDBConn" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I go to page behind and it recognizes my custom profile! I'm all exited until I run the page and get this:

### Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Now what? Pretty sure SimpleMembershiProvider doesn't use stored procedures like MembershipProvider use to, and I really don't want to install MembershipProvider in the database. There must be something I can add to my code so it works as is.

Any suggestions??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web.config is configured to use the default providers instead of the SimpleMembership providers.  Your web.config should look like this to use SimpleMembership.

```
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

SimpleMembership providers will not try to call the stored procedures used by the default providers.

Also, you cannot use ASP.NET Configuration to create users and roles when using SimpleMembership.  You have to create your own application to do this or seed the database when it created as [described in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html). This article, and most others on the Internet, are geared towards using SimpleMembership with MVC, not Web Forms. But as [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921221/simplemembership-with-webforms) point out it should work with Web Forms.

Comment: Its a website, not a project, so I won't let me install NuGet packages.

Comment: Does it have to be a website instead of web application project?  Here is a note from Microsoft where they recommend using web application projects going forward because of the very issues you are hitting [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx].

Comment: I'm going to try making a New Project and see if it works. Thanks.